# My divs line up from bottom to top instead of from top to bottom

Tags: css, html

I've got 6 different types of divs, 4 containers and 2 content divs, the content divs get printed multiple time with different content.

```
<div id="MainContainer">

      <div class="box_container">
        <div class="box_container_left">
          <div class="box_content_left">
             Test
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="box_container_right">
          <div class="box_content_right">
             Test2
          </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

If the divs are the same size, then nothing's wrong and the layout looks like intended, but if I add a line to the div, or add another content div, the layout goes all wrong.

I've did a little testing and it seemed that the bottom 2 divs are linked and the from that point go up.

```
.box_container{
        background-color:white;
        border: solid 3px black;
}

.box_container_left{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:40%;
    min-height:500px;
    background-color:red;
    border: solid 3px black;
}

.box_container_right{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:40%;
    min-height:500px;
    background-color:blue;
    border: solid 3px black;
}

.box_content_left{
    margin-top:3%;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    width:80%;
    background-color:green;
    min-height:20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border: solid 3px black;
}

.box_content_right{
    margin-top:3%;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    width:80%;
    min-height:20px;
    background-color:purple;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border: solid 3px black;
}
```

I haven't been able to find the problem, so if any off you know what the problem is I appreciate the help.

Comment: Not sure if this is going to help but I can see from your html that you aren't closing <div class="box_container">

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2p32M/
This is basically what happens. And as you can see the left div with test is at the same position as the second div on the right.

Comment: do you want it to be aligned next to each other or you want the blue div below the red one? One more thing, you are missing one closing <div> tag on the first content.

Comment: yeah, the 2 container divs next to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to `float` your `box_container_left`:

```
.box_container_left {
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2p32M/1/

Comment: I know this is years too late, but can you explain why this works?

Answer (score 1):

Put `vertical-align:top;` for both `.box-container_left` and `.box_container_right`. Here is the update [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2p32M/2/)

```
.box_container_left{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:40%;
    min-height:500px;
    background-color:red;
    border: solid 3px black;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.box_container_right{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:40%;
    min-height:500px;
    background-color:blue;
    border: solid 3px black;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```